# UI hangs when long search loop executed in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, worker

in my Winform a read file method is implemented on button click.when big files are read my Ui hangs until the loop is over.I need to have control on my UI all the time.

> i know that is done before and i tried some but i am still having an
>   error when i try to use some form controls like this :(translated!)

**the access of control element comboBox1 is from another thread rather than the thread in which it is created in !!!**

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

         {  
            //some code
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file,  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
                 {

                   while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
                   {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    UpdateProgressBar(line.Length);
                   }

                 }

              //some code
          }
```

Comment: Make a `Thread` that reads the file, so you won't block the UI-thread.

Comment: Man, this question comes up about once an hour now. **Please *search* before hitting "Submit"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to your class on Form (or Control) load. Then hookup its events:

```
BackgroundWorker _worker;
void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += _worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    _worker.ProgressChanged +=_worker_ProgressChanged;
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync(file);//pass on the file name
}

private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var file = e.Argument as String;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            _worker.ReportProgress(line.Length);
        }
    }
}

private void _worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Report porogress bar change
    UpdateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage);
}

private void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //do any stuff you want after reading the file.
}
```

Read more about this [here](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Using-Background-Worker-in-C.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the work on a separate thread.

Comment: would you please post more details.i am still not familiar with backgroundWorkers and threading in C#.

Comment: @user: [The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is great. That should be the first place you look. It contains a complete sample implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

[edit] Tutorial available [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Comment: would you please post more details.i am still not familiar with backgroundWorkers and threading in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You really should have consulted the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) before asking a question. Anyways, here's an example of how you can do it using a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
    worker.DoWork += ReadStream;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox1.Text);
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage);
    comboBox1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
}

private void ReadStream(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    string line;
    string comboBoxText = doWorkEventArgs.Argument.ToString();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            worker.ReportProgress(line.Length);
            worker.ReportProgress(line.Length, "NEW COMBOBOX TEXT");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you..i need to use comboBox1.text inside Readstream() and i am gettin an error (translated from german): the access of control element comboBox1 is from another thread rather than the thread in which it is created in...that was also happening before and really that is whay asked the question.

Comment: @user1096252 I've edited my answer to show you how. Notice that we supply an argument for RunWorkerAsync() and then extract it from doWorkEventArgs. Do you need to **change** the text of the comboBox?

Comment: no i just have to read them..the { WorkerReportsProgress = true }; is not working also.thanks.

Comment: By not working, do you mean it does not compile? What version of .NET are you compiling for? 4.0? 2.0?

Comment: yes now its ok..can i also send combobox2.text to readstream?

Comment: put the two strings into an array, like so: `string[] texts = new string[]{comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text};`. then, in `ReadStream(...)`, cast `doWorkEventArgs.Argument` back to an `Array` and use them. If you need help with this, mark your question as answered and open a new question asking how to pass an array as a parameter for doWork (or look it up on the internet).

Answer (score 0):

use backgroundworker to carry out heavy operations.
it has event to report progress of the task , so you can use it to update progress bar.